# Use of object literal function inside setTimeout

Tags: javascript, object, settimeout, literals

im having some code similar to this:

```
var options = {
    timerInterval: 800,
    timer: null
};

var functions = {
    someFunction: function() {

    }
};

options.timer = setTimeout('functions.someFunction()', options.timerInterval);
```

This won't fire though, because it can't find the functions object.

What to do? :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
options.timer = setTimeout(function () {
  functions.someFunction()
}, options.timerInterval)
```

it's not recommended to write your function argument as a string in a `setTimeout` b/c it has to do some conversions that adds overhead to your script and can be avoided by using an anonymous function to call your function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
options.timer = setTimeout(functions.someFunction, options.timerInterval);
```

But... the more robust way to do it is like this:

```
options.timer = setTimeout(function () {
    functions.someFunction();
}, options.timerInterval);
```

The second version is better because in JavaScript, the special variable `this` is dynamically scoped, which means that it will take the value from the scope it is evaluated in, not the scope it was defined in. Do a google search for "understanding javascript this" to find out more.

On a related note, ES5 introduces [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to deal with `this` problem.